# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure 'Usp_GetUserName_By_UserID'.'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am running into this exception when I try to login, the user is not yet registered in the database. I am testing some scenarios of my logic, if not registered. Do I need to create a stored procedure for that table from the database?

```
public string GetUserName_By_UserID(string UserId)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ToString())) 
    {
        var para = new DynamicParameters();
        para.Add("@UserId", UserId);

        return con.Query<string>("Usp_GetUserName_By_UserID", para, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to call a stored procedure, it must exist...

Answer (score 0):

Before calling a procedure from your MVC application please check that same one is existing in your Database also otherwise getting this kinds of errors.